# Flash DataGrid DataProvider Manipulation

Tags: flash, actionscript, datagrid, dataprovider

**Posting for a colleague. Please don't up-vote or down-vote.**

This is all inside the same MXML file.

```
public function toggleMonitor(part:Object):void { 
    if(part.active == 0)
        part.active = 1;
    else
        part.active = 0;
}

public function monitorAll(monitor:int):void {
    for(var part:Object in blah) {
        part.active = monitor;
    }
}

<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{blah}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:Image source="{data.active == 0 ? img1 : img2}" click="outerDocument.toggleMonitor(data)"/>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>  
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>

<mx:Button click="monitorAll(1)"/>
```

Clicking on the image correct toggles the image (i.e. the `toggleMonitor` function works). But clicking on the button doesn't (i.e. the `monitorAll` function does not work). Why isn't the button working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He managed to work out the issue. The method should be like this:

```
public function monitorAll(monitor:int):void {
    blah.refresh(); 
        for (var i:int = 0; i < blah.length; i++){
            (blah.getItemAt(i) as Object).active = monitor; 
        }
    blah.refresh(); 
}
```